# How to get a Tracking ID for Android an App? Analytics console is showing only Firebase option

Tags: android, firebase, google-analytics

How to get Tracking an ID for Android an App? Analytics console is showing only Firebase option.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

This is the only known workaround.

1. Create a new web property using type website.
2. Once you have created it then go and create a new view and you can create it of type mobile and get the tracking id without going though the FireBase stuff.